# Pushing a modified file in workspace to Github

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

As part of my Jenkins pipeline build I checkout my repo (which copies to my workspace I can see). I then modify a file in my workspace, which I then would like to push back up to my Github repo. I am just updating a version number in a podspec file.

```
node {
  stage 'Update File'
   env.WORKSPACE = pwd()
   File file = new File("${env.WORKSPACE}/ios.podspec");
   fileText = file.text;
   regex = "(spec.version\\s.*\$)";
   fileText = fileText.replaceAll(regex, "spec.version               =   '${VERSION}'\n".trim());
   file.write(fileText);

}
```

How can I take that file and push it back up to my Git repo?

Comment: is that file listed under `.gitignore`? Also are you able to modify that file in your local and commit the changes?

Comment: no it is not, so not sure what i am missing, and yes i can update locally

Comment: Quite simply by committing the file and pushing the changes. You have a locally checked out version, you might need to set your remote (I think the default is to have it detached from the remote), but other than that it is just normal git. Pick a tool that suits your pipeline and execute the commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sh "git checkout $branch"
sh "git add <your file>"
sh "git commit -m '...'"
sh "git push $url $branch"
```

The tricky part is to set the url with the relevant credentials
I am using this method -

```
def getRemoteUrlWithCredentials(credentialsId) {
    withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: credentialsId, usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD']]) {
        def scmUrl = scm.getUserRemoteConfigs()[0].getUrl()
        scmUrl = scmUrl.substring(scmUrl.indexOf("github.com"))
        return "https://${GIT_USERNAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD}@${scmUrl}"
    }
}
```

where credentialId is your git credentialsId. You will need to add `scm.getUserRemoteConfigs` to the approve list in Manage Jenkins -> In Process Script Approval.

And last part - I am not sure if it's necessary but maybe you'd need to set the config user.email and user.name ->

```
def setupConfig(email, userName) {
    sh "git config user.email $email"
    sh "git config user.name $userName"
}
```

Comment: thanks, in the end just using simple git commands work, no need to create a method

Comment: With ssh or https